# Why the Deserialize is not working?

Tags: c#, object, serialization

I've been working in a serialized object implementation using webServices, the data will be consumed by a desktop application I perform de following Operation in the webservices and it works fine:

```
        [WebMethod]
        public byte[] getPartners()
        {
            string[] strFiles = Directory.GetFiles(GlobalStatic.rootAppData + @"\partners");

            List<DentalSock.main.partner> _partners = new List<DentalSock.main.partner>();
            foreach (String str in strFiles)
            {
                DentalSock.main.partner ptn = new DentalSock.main.partner();
                ptn.readPartner(str.Replace(GlobalStatic.rootAppData + @"\partners\", "").Replace(".xml", ""));
                _partners.Add(ptn);
            }

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, _partners);
            return ms.ToArray();                  
        }
```

Then when I get back to the client consumer I call the webservice to deserialize the object into a generic list with the following code:

```
        ServiceReference1.partnerSoapClient p = new ServiceReference1.partnerSoapClient();
        byte[] byteArray = p.getPartners();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        pList = (List<partner>)bf.Deserialize(stream);
```

everything seems to work fine but in the last line when the Deserialize method is called nothing happens there is no exception and when I tried the debugger on goes step into debugger mode when the yellow highlighted line reaches the last line of the code above simply stops and show the windows form! 
Please help with this cause I don't get it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is now working pretty cool what I did was to put all the code under the DoWork event of a backgroundworker then I call the RunWorkerAsync() method on the Load event of the form and everything started to work the way around it was maybe related to the main thread.